# How to remove SPGroup from sitegroups using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, groups

How to remove a single SPGroup from SiteGroups from my SiteCollection using PowerShell.When I tried my code I am getting collection was modified error.
Lets  say the group name is "Group1" and I want to extract this group name using the sitegroups method of site's rootweb and delete the same.

Comment: Are you trying to remove custom site groups? or the OOB ones

Comment: @Asad, Thanks. Am trying to remove the one of the custom groups which is created by me.The name of the group is say "Group1". I have some 600+ SPGroups  created and I want to delete this Group1 for a particular reason.

Answer (score 5):

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb "https://spdev"
$GroupName="Group 1"

if($spWeb.SiteGroups[$GroupName] -ne $null)
{
$spWeb.SiteGroups.Remove($GroupName)
$spWeb.Update()
Write-Host "Group Deleted!"
}
else
{
Write-Host "Group doesn’t Exists!"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://siteurl"
$groups = $web.SiteGroups

$g = ("Group1")

ForEach($group in $g) {
   $groups.Remove($group)
}

$web.Dispose()
```

Comment: Never foreach while deleting or removing..

Answer (score 0):

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb "https://project"

Import-Csv c:\temp\projectgroups.csv | ForEach {

$GroupName=$_.GroupName

if($spWeb.SiteGroups[$GroupName] -ne $null)
{
$spWeb.SiteGroups.Remove($GroupName)
$spWeb.Update()
Write-Host "Group Deleted!"
}
else
{
Write-Host "Group doesn’t Exists!"
}
}
```