# How to delete SharePoint group using membershipgroupid in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell, permissions, groups

I am trying to move SharePoint Groups from one site collection to another.

In target site, the SharePoint groups got created. But the SP groups are showing in `groups.aspx` & not in `user.aspx`.

Also when I click the group name in `groups.aspx`, it throws error that Group cannot be found.

Also, unable to create with the same group name.

Comment: Are you trying to delete the SharePoint group using PowerShell or SharePoint REST API? Are you trying to move default SharePoint groups like Owners, Members, Visitors, etc.?

Comment: I am trying to delete using Powershell. No I am not trying to delete the default Sharepoint groups .  I have created custom SP groups from one site collection to another site collection . Now the newly created custom sharepoint groups are showing up in groups.aspx but when i click on the group name , it throws error that "group not found"

Answer (score 0):

To delete a SharePoint group using group ID, try something like this:

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb "https://spdev"
$groupId = 3

$group = $spWeb.SiteGroups.GetByID($groupId)

if($group -ne $null)
{
    $spWeb.SiteGroups.Remove($GroupName)
    
    #OR
    #$spWeb.SiteGroups.RemoveByID($groupId)
    
    $spWeb.Update()
    Write-Host "Group Deleted!"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Group doesn’t Exists!"
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can also delete the SharePoint group using it's name, like:

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb "https://spdev"
$GroupName="Group 1"

if($spWeb.SiteGroups[$GroupName] -ne $null)
{
    $spWeb.SiteGroups.Remove($GroupName)
    $spWeb.Update()
    Write-Host "Group Deleted!"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Group doesn’t Exists!"
}
```

**Source**: [How to remove SPGroup from sitegroups using PowerShell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/140007/how-to-remove-spgroup-from-sitegroups-using-powershell/140015)

Comment: Already tried with the above one's. It is throwing error that "Group not found".    $web.Sitegroups not listing those custom groups